# Add conditional group identifier using rollup functions

Tags: r, max, aggregation, mean, rollup

I have a data frame that has sub sequences (groups of rows)
and the condition to identify these sub sequences is to watch for a surge in the column diff. This is what the data looks like :

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(vid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    .Label = "2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5", class = "factor"), 
    events = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("click", 
    "mousedown", "mousemove", "mouseup"), class = "factor"), 
    deltas = structure(6:25, .Label = c("154875", "154878", "154880", 
    "155866", "155870", "38479", "38488", "38492", "38775", "45595", 
    "45602", "45606", "45987", "50280", "50285", "50288", "50646", 
    "54995", "55001", "55005", "55317", "59528", "59533", "59537", 
    "59921", "63392", "63403", "63408", "63822", "66706", "66710", 
    "66716", "67002", "73750", "73755", "73759", "74158", "77999", 
    "78003", "78006", "78076", "81360", "81367", "81371", "82381", 
    "93365", "93370", "93374", "93872"), class = "factor"), 
    serial = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
    19, 20), diff = c(0, 9, 4, 283, 6820, 7, 4, 381, 4293, 5, 3, 358, 4349, 6, 4,
    312, 4211, 5, 4, 384)), 
    .Names = c("vid", "events", "deltas", "serial", "diff"),
    row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to add a column that will indicate when a new sub sequence is identified and assign the entire sub sequence a unique id. I'll demonstrate the criterion for the grouping with the following example:
The diff value of row 5 is 6829 which is 10 times higher than the max value until that row (283). 
The result should be something like this df:

```
structure(list(vid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    .Label = "2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5", class = "factor"), 
    events = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("click", 
    "mousedown", "mousemove", "mouseup"), class = "factor"), 
    deltas = structure(6:25, .Label = c("154875", "154878", "154880", 
    "155866", "155870", "38479", "38488", "38492", "38775", "45595", 
    "45602", "45606", "45987", "50280", "50285", "50288", "50646", 
    "54995", "55001", "55005", "55317", "59528", "59533", "59537", 
    "59921", "63392", "63403", "63408", "63822", "66706", "66710", 
    "66716", "67002", "73750", "73755", "73759", "74158", "77999", 
    "78003", "78006", "78076", "81360", "81367", "81371", "82381", 
    "93365", "93370", "93374", "93872"), class = "factor"), serial = c(1, 
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
    19, 20), 
    diff = c(0, 9, 4, 283, 6820, 7, 4, 381, 4293, 5, 
    3, 358, 4349, 6, 4, 312, 4211, 5, 4, 384), 
    group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5)), 
    .Names =  c("vid", "events", "deltas", "serial", "diff", "group"), 
    row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: How about `df$group <- cumsum(df$diff > 500) + 1` (your whatever criteria you specify).

Comment: It works! but I don't understand why :-) the cumsum is only getting larger as R process row further down the df ?! don't see how this works, but it did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you a bit more detail on why it works and how it works.

First, let us just add a column without the `cumsum` part:

```
df$tag <- df$diff > 500
head(df)
                                   vid    events deltas serial diff   tag
1 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousemove  38479      1    0 FALSE
2 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousedown  38488      2    9 FALSE
3 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5   mouseup  38492      3    4 FALSE
4 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5     click  38775      4  283 FALSE
5 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousemove  45595      5 6820  TRUE
6 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousedown  45602      6    7 FALSE
```

As you can see, it simply creates a logical of TRUE/FALSE values in the tag column that says whether or not the difference is 'big enough' (based on selected threshold).

Now, when you do `cumsum` on that column and store it in `group` column, it will keep cumulatively adding. Every TRUE value will increment the cumulative sum by 1 and every FALSE value will keep the cumulative sum the same as it was before that row was hit.

So, this will give you the desired incrementing `group` values:

```
df$group <- cumsum(df$tag)
head(df)
                                   vid    events deltas serial diff   tag group
1 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousemove  38479      1    0 FALSE     0
2 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousedown  38488      2    9 FALSE     0
3 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5   mouseup  38492      3    4 FALSE     0
4 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5     click  38775      4  283 FALSE     0
5 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousemove  45595      5 6820  TRUE     1
6 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousedown  45602      6    7 FALSE     1
```

Notice that the group value starts at zero. Since cumulative sum of the first few FALSE values is zero. But, you may want your group identifiers to start with 1 instead. So, I added a 1 to the `cumsum`, but you can also do it as follows as an extra step.

```
df$group <- df$group + 1
head(df)
                                   vid    events deltas serial diff   tag group
1 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousemove  38479      1    0 FALSE     1
2 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousedown  38488      2    9 FALSE     1
3 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5   mouseup  38492      3    4 FALSE     1
4 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5     click  38775      4  283 FALSE     1
5 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousemove  45595      5 6820  TRUE     2
6 2a38ebc2-dd97-43c8-9726-59c247854df5 mousedown  45602      6    7 FALSE     2
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

courtesy of  the user Gopala :
How about df$group <- cumsum(df$diff > 500) + 1 (your whatever criteria you specify). – Gopala 31 mins ago